# Select2 Infinite scroll prepend options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown with the number of pages ( there can be 100k+ pages).

When i start from page lets say 40.000 if i scroll down i want to append the new pages to the list ( this is all okay ) but also i want to be able to scroll up and prepent the previous pages, and here i wasn't able to find any solution.

```
                CustomData.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {

                if (!("page" in params)) {
                    params.page = Math.ceil(page / pageSize);
                }

                if (params.term){
                    var results = items.filter(function(e) {
                        return e.text.indexOf(params.term) == 0;
                    });
                } else {
                    var results = items;
                }

                var data = {};
                data.results = results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize);
                data.pagination = {};
                data.pagination.more = params.page * pageSize < results.length;
                
                callback(data);
            };


            element.select2({
                ajax: {},
                multiple: false,    

                dataAdapter: CustomData,

                data : function() {
                    return [    
                        { 
                            id          : page , 
                            text        : page ,
                            selected    : true
                        }
                    ]
                }(),                    
            })
```